# Pandas Multi-indexing from a Flatten DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to resample flatten dataframe to multi-indexed columns.
Dataframe looks like  :

```
goods category month stock
a       c1     1     5
a       c1     2     0
a       c1     3     0
a       c2     1     0
a       c2     2    10
a       c2     3     0
b       c1     1    30
b       c1     2     0
b       c1     3    10
b       c2     1     0
b       c2     2    40
b       c2     3     0
```

And I would like to set him like this :

```
stock            
goods        a       b    
category    c1  c2  c1  c2
month                     
1            5   0  30   0
2            5  10  30  40
3            5  10  10  40
```

I try somethings with groupby or stack but I don't find a good way...Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `unstack` (to use this you first have to set the multi-index):

```
In [48]: df.set_index(['goods', 'category', 'month']).unstack([0,1])
Out[48]:
         stock
goods        a       b
category    c1  c2  c1  c2
month
1            5   0  30   0
2            0  10   0  40
3            0   0  10   0
```

Alternative with `pivot_table` (but be aware, if you have multiple values with the same combination of goods/category/month, they will be averaged by default (another function can be specified)):

```
In [54]: df.pivot_table(columns=['goods', 'category'], index='month', values='stock')
Out[54]:
goods     a       b
category c1  c2  c1  c2
month
1         5   0  30   0
2         0  10   0  40
3         0   0  10   0
```